# Building Connection Between Power pivot and SAS using VBA

Tags: vba, sas, powerpivot

I'm trying to build a connection between Power Pivot and SAS so that I can import my SAS dataset directly to Power Pivot Data Model, using VBA. I'm using the Add2 function and keeps getting the same error message:

Run-time error '1004':
We couldn't get data from the Data Model. Here's the error message we got:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Please help me fix the problem. Thanks in advance.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddPowerPivotModel()

  ThisWorkbook.Connections.Add2 _
    "test", _
    "", _
    "OLEDB;Provider=sas.IOMProvider.9.44;Data Source=_LOCAL_;", _
    "select * from sashelp.class", _
    XlCmdType.xlCmdSql, _
    True, True

End Sub
```

Comment: Build the connection manually and try to execute "select * from sashelp.class" over it. See if it returns data or throws an error.

Comment: That I tried and it worked just fine. However, I need to automate the build connection step 'cause we have too many datasets at different location that needs to be added to power pivot.

Comment: Just a quite update. It seems like the connection was built (if I delete the last 2 parameters) but no data is retrieved from the dataset, which is weird